# How to set TTL on one record rather than on an entire row?

Tags: spring, cassandra, spring-data, spring-data-cassandra

Is there any way in Cassandra to set TTL for only one record (one column), not for entire row. For ex, there is a table which has temporary users data and in it their is a field OTP which expires in 30 minutes. I'm trying to figure out how to set TTL only on OTP record not on entire user field row.

All the examples I found so far sets TTL on entire row not on any specific record.
I'm using Spring Data for Cassandra.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Insert the field using separate query with TTL**

If your table name is `users` and primary key is `userid` then insert the `OTP` field with `userid` using TTL 30 * 60 = 1800 seconds

```
INSERT INTO users(userid, OTP) values(?, ?) USING TTL 1800;
```